# Elmah RSS Feed Error

Tags: asp.net, rss, elmah

I've got Elmah in an ASP.net app using the xml log files. Viewing the errors through the /elmah.axd works, however when trying to hit /elmah.axd/rss it throws an error:

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\zszuhfnh.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified
```

Am I missing a step?